# Kubernetes Ressource Usage - Realworld Experience?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm tasked with developing a container network that is supposed to run on older hardware, i have therefore **ressource constraints** with servers in the 4 to 8GB RAM range.

As for now we have everything running on Docker, here it's around 8-10 *very lightweight Containers* and **things are tight but alright**.

I have started digging into *Kubernetes* as we have edgecases where we would need to scale to a 100+ of these containers on multiple servers.

We are considering adding Kubernetes as a default Wrapper over everything, even our currently well running smaller Docker network.

However i could not find any reasonable estimate regarding just the Kubernetes overhead; there's official sources stating you need already 2GB (!!) just for the runtime. It is hard to believe for me that it is THAT wasteful. Given its actual tasks I would've estimated maybe like 30-50MB.

Has anyone real-world numbers/experience regarding Kubernetes overhead?
E.g. how much more % of CPU/RAM does your network need simply by adding a Kubernetes layer on top?

Answer (score 1):

I think here no blanket statement can be made because a “naked” Kubernetes does not bring you much. You need various helpers, such as a network plugin. But if you want to implement your solution with Kubernetes but require a more resource efficient distribution, then it's worth looking into *MicroK8s* or *K3s*  [comparison](https://microk8s.io/compare).

How many resources your cluster needs depends on what you run on which servers, a worker node definitely needs less than a node running the control-plane.

Comment: Didn't know about MicroK8's until now, great input, thanks a lot.